# ajax request is not sending on ie11

Tags: jquery, ajax, smarty

i have spent all day on this, reading and reading and trying different things and i still cannot get the ajax request to send in ie11.  So i have pretty much stipped this down to nothing and as you an see i have cache set to false and also added a random number on the end of the url in order to not be cached by ie.  FF and Chrome work fine... i have a file_put_contents set up ine the php file for the request and i get the array in that file with both FF and chrome when i run this code, but IE there is nothing... help please.. thanks :)

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">

/* yes the literals are backwords thats how it works */
/* for smarty in js - see smarty forum */
/* addEventListener is ok we do not support < ie9 */

"use strict";

var r = '?ran='+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) +1);
var ajaxurl = {/literal} '{$ajaxUrl}'{literal};
var roomid  = {/literal} '{$room}' {literal};
var userid  = {/literal} '{$userid}' {literal};
var urlwithr = ajaxurl+r;

window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {

$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  method: 'GET',
  url: urlwithr,
  data: {
         roomid: roomid,
         userid: userid,
         urlwr: urlwithr,
         ajax: true
        },
   success: function() {
   /* nothing dont need it */
   }
  });
 });
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Anything in javascript console? Any error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code works in general. I think it's more a problem of the `unload` event in IE11. To test this, try to execute the code without the event in IE11 or use another event type. Just to be sure.

Comment: nope nothing, completely clean :(

Comment: i did try attachEvent and same thing nothing from ie... ok ill try it without the event :)

Comment: ok i removed the event from the function and now it works :) on ie, but it only works if i refresh the page, it does not work if i leave the page which is what i need.

Comment: Yes, but now you know your problem. It's not your ajax, it is your used event registration. `window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {});`. ;) You can try other events, like `beforeunload`.

Comment: thank you so very much that is a huge help. your awesome :)  i much prefer the server side of things, seems every time i have to work on the user side i spend days on one or two features lol  Thanks again :)

Comment: ok so the whole issue here is that IE prefers beforeunload and FF prefers unload.  So in my hunt i found this great tool (i think lol)  Here is the article http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/ and here is the github of it  http://kangax.github.io/iseventsupported/  from reading about it, it allows you to test for both and process accordingly without using browser sniffing.  Now i just have to learn how to use it... :)

Comment: and of course like most things you find on the net, id does not work.. grrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to eisbehr for this answer... kudos :) here is what worked, the rest of the code is the same.  What is ironic is that this is pretty much what i started with and i have gone all the way around the block from tons of code to back to this. I started using unload in the early stages because i did not like the fact that beforeunload had a alert and what if they said no to the alert.  But now it seems to be working fine with no alert, and all of this just because of the word 'event' lol

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
```

thanks again eisbehr...

Comment: Back to work on this and now it wont work on FireFox but works on IE. Do i have to make a choice to support one or the other :(

Comment: You could try `$(window).one("unload beforeunload", function() {})`. Untested, maybe work. :)

Comment: yes sir eisbehr it works perfectly, now i can remove my browser snif code that i did not want to use in the first place... thanks so much :)  good man...